# About the construction of Quot-Schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes

I am reading in the paper of Nitsure (link: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504590v1.pdf) about the construction of the Quot-scheme $\mathrm{Quot}_{E/X/S}^{\Phi,L}$. After Lemma 5.4. they reduce to the case where $E$ is the pullback of a vector bundle on $S$ and $X=\mathbb{P}(V)$ is some projective space. I understand the proof of Lemma 5.4., and the lemma implies that we can assume $E$ as above. But how does the reduction to $X=\mathbb{P}(V)$ work?

Is it true, that there is an isomorphism of functors $\mathrm{Quot}_{E/X/S}^{\Phi,L} \rightarrow \mathrm{Quot}_{E'/\mathbb{P}(V)/S}^{\Phi,L}$ when $X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}(V)$ is a closed subscheme? At least there's a morphism from the right to the left by taking pullbacks. However, I don't see how an inverse would look like.
Or is there a closed embedding $\mathrm{Quot}_{E/X/S}^{\Phi,L} \rightarrow \mathrm{Quot}_{E'/\mathbb{P}(V)/S}^{\Phi,L}$ which would suffice as well?

Here is some other idea: a quotient of $E$ on $X$ is the same as a quotient of the pushforward $i_{\ast}E$ on $\mathbb{P}(V)$. But is it guaranteed, that $i_{\ast}E$ is still a quotient of some $\pi^{\ast}W$?

Comment: Quite honestly, I don't understand the downvote. I shall upvote only to cancel it - an approach I do not like.

Comment: Isn't this just what it means to have a closed immersion of functors? Given functors from schemes to sets $F,G$, then we say a natural transformation $\eta : F \to G$ is a closed immersion if for any scheme $X$ and natural transformation $h_X \to G$, the fiber product of the three functors is representable by a closed subscheme by $X$. In particular if $G$ is representable by a scheme, then we can base change by the identity $h_G \to h_G$ to conclude that $F$ is a scheme too.

Comment: Hi. Could you please tell me, what is the resolution of this question? I had the exact same question as I am reading the article.

Comment: Never mind. I think I figured it out. The first one is closed subfunctor of the second one. So it is fine.